# DateTime.TryParseExact with "U" and DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime, date-formatting

How should a date/time string be formatted so that it can be parsed by [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) with the "U" format string and `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`? In other words, what is a valid `timestampString` so that `isDateTime` is set to `true` in the following code?

```
string timestampString = "...";

DateTime timestamp;
bool isDateTime = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    timestampString, "U", null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out timestamp);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example for the en-US culture:

```
string timestampString = "Saturday, April 20, 2013 9:00:00 PM";

DateTime timestamp;
bool isDateTime = DateTime.TryParseExact(timestampString, "U", null,
    DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out timestamp);

Console.WriteLine(isDateTime);     // True
Console.WriteLine(timestamp);      // 4/20/2013 9:00:00 PM
Console.WriteLine(timestamp.Kind); // Utc
```

As documented under the [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#UniversalFull) topic in MSDN Library, "U" represents the format defined by the [DateTimeFormatInfo.FullDateTimePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.fulldatetimepattern.aspx) property, with an automatic conversion to UTC. For en-US, this format is `"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`.

Answer (score 1):

From [this MSDN post:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb504692.aspx)

> **AdjustToUniversal** Parses the string represented by input and, if
>   necessary, converts it to UTC. It is equivalent to parsing a string
>   and then calling the DateTimeOffset.ToUniversalTime method of the
>   returned DateTimeOffset object.

So, try first to parse your date.

I am not sure the format "U" is valid for date time. For example, I did not found it on [MSDN date time formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) page